# Easy to use graphics software to crop and resize and not much more

Tags: windows, images, image-editor

Need something that a technophobe could use to simply crop and resize images before uploading. Other options need to be kept at a minimum.

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) is great, but there are just too many options.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried [Paint.NET](http://getpaint.net) ?

[image: Paint.Net]

It's often the perfect cross between MSPaint and Photoshop for me. It has basic support for a wide range of filetypes, and your basic drawing tools and image operations (resizing, cropping, etc.). It still has a lot of options, but it's free and *feels* like MSPaint, which I imagine the user is more familiar with than say, GIMP. For Crop & Resize, just tell them to ignore the Layers, Adjustments, and Effects menus.

All your technophobe needs to do is:

- **File > Open**
- Click the selection tool (Top-left tool in the toolbox)
- Select the desired area of the image they want
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or **Image > Crop to Selection** to crop out the rest of the image they don't want
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or **Image > Resize...** to open up the resize dialog and enter in the width or height they want to resize the image to
- **File > Save As...**

Comment: Paint.NET has a few too many options than I would have liked, but I've been having a play and it is certainly intuitive and handles the cropping/resizing requirement very well.

Answer (score 2):

**[Paint](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/paint)** allows you to very easily crop and resize images.

#### Pros

- Easy to use
- Has been a part of default Windows programs for a long time

#### Cons

- Lacks precise selection
- Resizing is a bit odd, but works.

[image: Crop, Resize]

#### Cropping

- Open the image file
- Select an area with the select tool
- Press Crop

#### Resizing

- Open the image file
- Select an area with the select tool
- Resize it to what you want it to be
- Deselect (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and resize the whole white area down to the same size.

Comment: Whilst Paint has been "part of Windows for a long time", it should be noted that this particular version comes with Windows 7/8. Earlier versions don't offer enough control. For instance, Paint with WinVista only allows you to resize to a percentage and does not maintain aspect ratio (unless you specifically do this yourself). I do quite like the newer Paint for these features, however, one BIG irritation is that you can't resize or move the actual selection. Attempting to do so resizes/moves the selected portion of the image itself.

Comment: Regarding your method of "resizing"... I think it would be preferable, if you wished to resize just a portion of the image, to select and crop the required area first and then use the _resize dialog_ to resize the resulting image. Attempting to resize with the mouse is hopeless as there appears to be no way to lock the aspect ratio. [Ctrl]+[D] does not appear to be a valid shortcut in Paint. [Esc] deselects the current selection.

Comment: @w3d hm, it worked for me on win8, but good points.

Comment: I'm on Win7 - maybe there are differences?

Answer (score 1):

FastStone Image Viewer is a great image viewer and can do quick and simple crop and resize and a few other things.  It's the best in this category and it's free.
http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm